# List<User> not Removing POJO Object it Contains in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm reading data of Users (Name,Age) from Firebase Database and showing it in a recycler view. When the user long click an item, that item is deleted from firebase successfully but when I try to remove that item from List of users , e.g List , in the child listener's onChildRemoved method, the user is not removed. The code is:

```
mChildListener=new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                User user=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                user.setUid(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                mDataList.add(user);
                mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //passing the user returned to adapter but didn't work
                mUserAdapter.updateDataSet(user);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {  
                User user=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                user.setUid(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                mDataList.remove(user);
                mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
```

This is User Model Class:

```
public class User {
    private String uid;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public User() {}
    public User(String uid, String name, int age) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getUid() {return uid;}
    public void setUid(String uid) {this.uid = uid;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public int getAge() {return age;}
    public void setAge(int age) {this.age = age;}
}
```

The recycler view code is this:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        User user=mDataList.get(position);

        holder.textView.setText(user.getName()+ "  |  "+user.getAge());

        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String uid=user.getUid();
                Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(USER_KEY,uid);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        holder.textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                //this line returns true
                boolean remove = mDataList.contains(user);
                //if I try to remove the user here, its removed
                //this line works as I want
//                mDataList.remove(user);
                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "updateDataSet: Contains: "+remove);
                Task<Void> removeUser = NetworkUtils.removeUser(user.getUid());
                removeUser.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "User removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //mDataList.remove(user);
                        //notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

I also tried to pass the User returned in onChildRemoved to the adapter, but that doesn't work as well.

```
public void updateDataSet(User user){
        //this also returns false even the data of this user id displayed
        boolean contains=mDataList.contains(user);
        //this also does not works
        mDataList.remove(user);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

My Questions are:

1) How can I remove the item deleted on long item click from the recycler view list as well?

2) I have `List<User> mDataList` in `MainActivity.java` and one in `UserAdapter.java`.
I'm passing the `mDataList` in `MainActivity` to the `UserAdapter`.
Are these two same in memory or different? If different, then how changing the `List<user> mDataList` in `MainActivity` (adding newly items in `onChildAdded`) changes the `List<User> mDataList` in `UserAdapter`?
Thanks a lot.
I've tried my best to clear my questions as possible.

Comment: where you are calling onChildRemoved?

Comment: I'm attaching the child listener to the Database reference in onCreate of main activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your User class with equals() method:

```
public class User {
    private String uid;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public User() {}
    public User(String uid, String name, int age) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getUid() {return uid;}
    public void setUid(String uid) {this.uid = uid;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public int getAge() {return age;}
    public void setAge(int age) {this.age = age;}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof User) {
            User user= (User) obj;
            return uid.equals(user.getUid());
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

Now update your onChildRemoved method:

```
@Override
public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
      User user=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
      user.setUid(dataSnapshot.getKey());
      int index = mDataList.indexOf(user);
      mDataList.remove(index);
      mUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Note: If uid does not exist in mDataList, it will return -1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problems solved. I thought of this but didn't tried. Can you explain why I need to override the equals method? and what you say about my second question? Thanks again. Please up vote the question as this will help me in future questions.

Comment: overrdiding the equals method can directly give you the index without using for loop or iterator. I upvoted already.

Comment: Thanks. After overriding equals method,the remove method worked even without getting index. What you about second question in my post?

Comment: It depends on how you are declaring arraylist in adapter. If you are creating arraylist with new keyword, obviously it will take different memory and if you are just declaring the arrayList i.e. List<User> mArrayList; , in this case it will not take different memory. Please accept the answer or upvote if it helps you.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. And answer is accepted and upvoted.